# Black screen during remote assistance (MSRA.EXE)

Tags: windows, remote-access, vmware-workstation

I've tried:

- Disabling UAC
- Every bandwidth optimization option
- Unchecking all boxes in the Performance Options:Visual Effects tab

But still, every time, all they see is a black screen with my mouse cursor moving about.

Environment is:

- Remote Assistance requestor (server): Windows 8.1 VMware guest
- Remote Assistance responder (client): Windows 7, Windows 8.1

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I remember when I had this issue in my environment.  Per the following link https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee844127%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

In your Group Policy (gpedit.msc) settings (If domain, apply to the appropriate Organizational Unit), go to Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options.

Change the following setting **User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation** to **disabled**.

EDIT
Remember to update your computers with the latest group policy change. 
In CMD Prompt run gpupdate /force to update your computers to the latest group policy settings. 
To open cmd prompt, in Windows, click in your Search bar and type in Command Prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I recently created this PowerShell solution which can be used when need to open a Remote Assistance session and type in the elevated UAC credential that cannot be share with the end-user being assisted.

Technically you can run just the `Invoke-Command` and point it to the remote computer, and then ensure the `Set-ItemProperty` has the appropriate `1` or `0` value for "`PromptOnSecureDesktop`" to enable or disable.

I wanted to ensure that when I need to run `msra` in an elevated session, I can just execute the script and be assured the UAC secure desktop security is re-enabled automatically after the `msra` session has ended.

> **Essentially this will...**
>
> - prompt you for the computer name
> - disable the "UAC secure desktop" via the remote registry change and commands
> - start an `msra` session that works same way it works always works from here
> - enable the "UAC secure desktop" via the remote registry change and commands once the correlated `msra` instance ends
>
> **To use you only need to...**
>
> 1. Save the PowerShell script as a text document with a `.ps1` file name extension
> 2. Open a PowerShell command prompt and type (or paste) in the full script path and filename, and press <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>
> 3. Enter in the computer name of the computer you are connecting to with remote assistance and  press <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>.
> 4. When done with the remote assistance session, close the `mrsa` process if it's still running

**Tip:** Use the non-elevated "other/standard" method of `msra` most of the time, and only use this as-needed.

## PowerShell Script

```
$pc = Read-Host "Enter the remote computer name to disable secure desktop";

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -Scriptblock {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "PromptOnSecureDesktop" -Value 0 -Force;
    };

$remoteAssist = "$Env:windir\system32\msra.exe";
Start-Process $remoteAssist "/offerra" -Wait;
Write-Host "Your Remote assist session has ended" -ForegroundColor Red;

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -Scriptblock {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "PromptOnSecureDesktop"  -Value 1 -Force;
    };
```

**Execute Example**

*Note: Just paste in the full path script name and press enter.*

```
PS C:\Users\User> \\myserver.domain.com\sharename\folder\script\Elevate-RemoteAssist.ps1
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- > #### [User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-switch-to-the-secure-desktop-when-prompting-for-elevation)
  >
  > The secure desktop presents the logon UI and restricts functionality
  >   and access to the system until the logon requirements are satisfied.
  >
  > The secure desktop’s primary difference from the user desktop is that
  >   only trusted processes running as `SYSTEM` are allowed to run here
  >   (that is, nothing is running at the user’s privilege level). The path
  >   to get to the secure desktop from the user desktop must also be
  >   trusted through the entire chain.
  >
  > #### Possible values
  >
  > - **Enabled**
  >
  >   - All elevation requests by default go to the secure desktop.
  > - **Disabled**
  >
  >   - All elevation requests go to the interactive user desktop.
  >
  > [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-switch-to-the-secure-desktop-when-prompting-for-elevation)
- [Invoke-Command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html)
- [Set-ItemProperty](https://ss64.com/ps/set-itemproperty.html)
- [Start-Process](https://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html)

  > ```
  >  -Wait
  >    Wait for the specified process to complete before accepting more input.
  >    This parameter suppresses the command  prompt or retains the window
  >    until the process completes
  > ```

Comment: Interesting, would you like to adapt this for use with **Quick Assist**? `C:\windows\system32\quickassist.exe` – it will probably fit nicely as an answer elsewhere (not under `MSRA.EXE`). Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66920815/38108 I'm struggling (PowerShell is quite new to me) …

Answer (score 0):

I would get the same thing using RDP at my last job.  I would remote to caller, it would require admin user/pass which I couldn't give them or see the prompt to enter.  Just got a black screen that said pause.

To resolve according to MS forums, Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > User Account Control : Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation.  Check Define this policy setting and select Disabled.

However our GPO, at my last job, was causing the problem and I couldn't convince anyone to step in and resolve.  So I moved to Bomgar as a remote assistance solution.